# How do I add Anaconda python kernel to jupyter (Ipython)?

Tags: ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My (school cluster's) system is python-2.7.5, and I installed a anaconda python 2.7.12 on it.

When I use ipython notebook, it uses school's default version. How can I add anaconda's version in the kernel?

I want to do this because: I want to use netCDF4 package, but my school's python cannot load this package, while the anaconda's version is OK.

(BTW, why can I use ipython notebook in school's cluster (in my browser)? I use [ssh to connect it](http://www.hydro.washington.edu/~jhamman/hydro-logic/blog/2013/10/04/pybook-remote/).)

Comment: You shouldn't have installed anaconda over an existing python installation. Just remove anaconda and install netCDF4 using `pip`.

Comment: Thanks! I see. Then the only way to solve this is to bug our administrator who can sudo.

Comment: BTW, if not ipython notebook (only python or ipython), this can be simply solved my add the anaconda's path to the PATH variable in the .bashrc file. However, it seems that even I do this, the ipython notebook always find the school's default python.

Comment: well, it seems that when I use `jupyter notebook` instead of `ipython notebook`, it can automatically detect the two different versions of python -- one is default, another is "conda root". Even though I don't know why.

Comment: It should be possible to [install a kernel](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) from Anaconda, so that Jupyter will find it (assuming they're on the same machine).